# Authorized failed when run Google.Apis.YouTube.Samples.Upload project from Github

Tags: c#, google-api, google-oauth, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am new from youtube api. I would like to have a console program schedule upload videos to youtube without authorization everytime.

I see many posts and videos but not the complete story, I download the sample from Github and try to run it. It failed.

i follow the guide that

。create OAuth client ID and application type choose Other

。download code from github

。click allow in browser, lets youtube api manage youtube account.

[image]

[img1 - client secret download from console developer and code from github](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6jmE.png)

[img2 - error message told me unauthorized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lJgjQ.png)
[image]

which part is wrong, how can i fix it? Please help!

Comment: In the future please post your code and not a screen shot of your code

Comment: please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 0):

The error your getting means that you have not authenticated the YouTubeService there must be something wrong with your credentials which i cant see because you haven't posted all your code.

The YouTube API does not support service accounts. You will need to authenticate your code at least once.  This is done via a web browser and the client library you are using will store the credentials for "user" in %appData% directory.

The tutorial you are following doesn't say anything about not needing authentication.   This is the code for the auth.

```
UserCredential credential;
      using (var stream = new FileStream("client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
      {
        credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
            GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
            // This OAuth 2.0 access scope allows for full read/write access to the
            // authenticated user's account.
            new[] { YouTubeService.Scope.Youtube },
            "user",
            CancellationToken.None,
            new FileDataStore(this.GetType().ToString())
        );
      }
```

Comment: the sample program also include the partial code you provide. I am new so i only can post two links in the post.

Comment: @Dalm,  exactly the same with yours, but error is unauthorized. Is the network, proxy, firewall affect?